# How to change Android button color onClick?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, onclick

I wanted to change the android button color every time I click on a button. Once a user clicks a button, I want it so that the color changes. Then, when the button is pressed again, the color reverts back to what it was before. Here is my attempt:

```
private void setupFollowButton(Button button, final Boolean isClicked) {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Boolean isClickedDummy = !isClicked;
            if(isClickedDummy) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Originally I wanted it so that `isClicked = !isClicked` so that I would know for certain that the `isClicked` variable has changed and I can change the color. However, the method I have above only changes the `isClicked` to false and I can't seem to change it back to `true`. Is there any way I can figure this out? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i think it always takes the default value of isClicked whenever yo click button

Comment: so every time you will getting only one value of isClicked

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 isClicked = false;   

     private void setupFollowButton(Button button, final Boolean isClicked) {
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isClicked) {
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        isClicked = false;
                    } else {
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        isClicked = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can xml drawable :

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:background="@drawable/selector_xml_name"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="126dp"
     android:text="Hello" />
```

selector_xml_name.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the value of "isClickedDummy" and you have to use it as global.

```
Boolean isClickedDummy; // global after the declaration of your class

isClickedDummy = true; // in your onCreate() 

private void setupFollowButton(Button button, final Boolean isClicked) {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isClickedDummy) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                isClickedDummy = false;
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                isClickedDummy = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to remove `BackgroundResource` of your button if you want to change the background color.

That is, use:

`btn.setBackgroundResource(0);`

After that, 'usual  button layout' will disappear and I will show the changes of `setBackground` method.